# Re-do the current Iteration of a for loop in python

Tags: python

So, I am doing a for loop to iterate over a list of reports and am thinking of ways to redo the current iteration if a condition holds true. Following is what I do

```
for report in reports:
    check_if_table_exists_in_SQL_DATABASE_for_report_name
    download_report_using_request_in_csv
    preprocess_file_to_change_it
    get_Column_names_from_csv_file
    if check_if_table_exists_in_SQL_DATABASE_for_report_name = False:# table doesnt exist in DB
        create table
    else
        if cols_in_sql_table != cols_in_Csv_file:
            drop_Current_table
            goto_Start_of_the_current_iteration #<<<<< **THIs is what i need help with**
```

So you see ideally the best case would be a goto statement, but I guess that is frowned upon...so checking whats the best way to do this.

Comment: If you really want to redo the current iteration, I would turn the `for` loop into a `while` loop (which means you maintain the variable `report` by yourself, by initializing it before the loop, incrementing it at the end of the loop, and checking the end condition in the `while` statement).  Then, since you control the incrementing logic, you can decide to not increment it (e.g. with a `continue`)

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops don't really natively support this, but I suppose you could to this with some kind of hack:

```
def redoable(iterable): 
    do_redo = False 
    def redo():
        nonlocal do_redo 
        do_redo = True 
    for item in iterable: 
        yield redo, item 
        while do_redo: 
            do_redo = False 
            yield redo, item
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
for redo, report in redoable(reports):
    check_if_table_exists_in_SQL_DATABASE_for_report_name
    download_report_using_request_in_csv
    preprocess_file_to_change_it
    get_Column_names_from_csv_file
    if check_if_table_exists_in_SQL_DATABASE_for_report_name = False:# table doesnt exist in DB
        create table
    else:
        if cols_in_sql_table != cols_in_Csv_file:
            drop_Current_table
            redo()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generator `send` protocol to create a version that replays the provided value:

```
def repeatable(obj):
    for x in obj:
        y = yield x
        while y is not None:
            yield None  # this gets consumed by the call to `send`
            y = yield y
```

Here you can use `gen.send(val)` to have `gen` repeat `val` on the next iteration. Here's an example:

```
repeat = repeatable(range(5))
repeat_me = {2, 3}
for x in repeat:
    print(x)
    if x in repeat_me:
        repeat.send(x)  # replays `x` on the next iteration
        repeat_me.remove(x)
```

Comment: @L3viathan Oops, thanks for the pointer, that was a remnant from a previous version when I though that `repeat_me` would be more expressive than `stuff` :-) Apparently it remained somehow at the definition though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an additional `for` loop nested into the original one in order to loop over the tables:

```
for report in reports:
    ...
    for table in get_tables_for_report(report):
        if cols_in_sql_table != cols_in_Csv_file:
            drop_table(table)
        else:
            break
    else:
        create_table()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`more_itertools.seekable`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.seekable) for repeating the last element. To do so you need to specify `seekable(..., maxlen=1)` and then you can use `.seek(0)` to repeat the most recently yielded element:

```
from more_itertools import seekable

repeat = seekable(range(5), maxlen=1)
repeat_me = {2, 3}
for x in repeat:
    print(x)
    if x in repeat_me:
        repeat.seek(0)
        repeat_me.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is put the whole logic inside a infinite while loop.
And then your exit conditions to break out of the loop.

This is just a pseudo code

```
exit_flag=True
While True:
    for ...loop:
        code1
        code2
        code3
        If condition:
             code
        Else:
             If condition:
                 code
                 exit_flag= False
                 break
    If exit_flag == True:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class to manage the iterable (reports) and allow you to force a certain number of repetitions from within the loop:

```
class Repeatable:
    def __init__(self,iterable):
        self.iterable   = iterable

    def __iter__(self):
        for result in self.iterable:
            self.repeat = None
            yield result
            while self.repeat:
                yield result
                self.repeat -= 1
```

Usage:

```
newReports = Repeatable(reports)  # <-- encapsulate the iterator
for report in newReports:         # <-- iterate over the encapsulation
    check_if_table_exists_in_SQL_DATABASE_for_report_name
    download_report_using_request_in_csv
    preprocess_file_to_change_it
    get_Column_names_from_csv_file
    if check_if_table_exists_in_SQL_DATABASE_for_report_name = False:# table doesnt exist in DB
        create table
    else
        if cols_in_sql_table != cols_in_Csv_file:
            drop_Current_table
            newReports.repeat = 1 # <-- force one more iteration with current value
```